# Microsoft Access giving ASYNC_NETWORK_IO on new PC Build

Tags: ms-access

Background:

I've been supporting a legacy MS Access Front end with Linked Tables to SQL Server for about a year. The code is terrible, and we're re-writing as an MVC App. But for the next year or so we still have to support it.

Last week I upgraded my laptop. More RAM, bigger HHD etc ... On my old laptop, I had a copy of the SQL Express Database, and the Access, and it ran fine. I open a form in Access, and it appeared after a couple of seconds.

New laptop. Twice the RAM ... takes minutes to load the same form with the same database running locally. When I look at the SQL Server, I see the queries that the Access is calling and they're all with ASYNC_NETWORK_IO

My task manager on my PC shows memory running at 40%, and CPU at 30%. There is no network as Access and SQL are on the same PC.

Does anyone know why the Access front end would be taking minutes on my new laptop, compared to seconds on the old, to load the same form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for the next unfortunate person who has the issue.

- On my old laptop I was running SQL Express 2019
- On my new laptop I installed SQL Developer Edition 2019

Clutching at straws, I installed Express 2019 on the new laptop, changed the connection string, and it's back to working normally!

Unbelievable that using Developer Edition caused so much more heartache than Express ... would love if someone could answer that for me!

Comment: For really small tables - say only 500,000 to 1 million rows, my dumpster laptop with a 1.7 ghz process usually loads forms and Access loads well under 1 second.  I doubt that the version of SQL server makes a difference. In 99% of these cases, the issue is some network connection or that you have a stray table linked (pointing) to a non existing network connection - and thus you get these large delays.  You could check if you had (have) named pipes or TC/IP disabled. But in most cases, probably re-linking the tables (and thus removing the incorrect linked table pointing nowhere) was the fix.

Comment: I suppose you perhaps dealing with large tables - but relative tiny small tables in the 1 million row range should allow access to load and work instant. This is some other issue then the version of SQL server - but that of some network issue. In most cases, this is a stray (wrong) linked table that points to a non existing connection that causes these issues - not just out of the blue swapping out the version of sql server. It likly that your re-linking fixed this and not the change of sql server.

Comment: it's all local, both the Access and SQL. since making this post (and answer), I've changed the connection string back to Developer Edition, and it's back to the original issue. Odd that different versions of SQL are producing this. when I get time, I'm going to replicate on another PC, with both versions of SQL and see if it's the same result.

Comment: I would try disable of named pipes - enable tc/ip. I don't suppose odbc tracing is on for one, and not for the other. You could also as noted try re-linking tables with native 17 or later as opposed to the legacy drivers. These delays are noted in this post (and was fixed by disable of named pipes --- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Oct/26/Sql-Server-Slow-Connections-with-2-second-or-so-delay